# SQL Server Management Studio: insert comment in view definition

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

It is possible to insert comments in views in SQL Server Management Studio (2005)? I talk about the window that you see after you right click on a view in the object explorer and choose *Modify*.

I tried to insert different kind of comments in the SQL code but it all leads to syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me - when I "script as -> create", the comment shows up.

```
create view [dbo].[v_test] as 
/* this is my view */
select * from Items
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sadly the comment is not shown in the _Modify_ window.